# aiohttp: exception=TimeoutError()

Tags: python, python-3.x, async-await, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I have `test.py` and `AsyncioCurl.py` files.
I run `python .\Src\test.pt` and give me this error.

```
PS C:\Users\Thinkpad\Desktop\BilibiliHelper> python .\Src\test.py
2019-02-22 10:28:27,696 - C:\Users\Thinkpad\Desktop\BilibiliHelper\Src\Log.py[line:56] - DEBUG: GET: https://api.live.bilibili.com/room/v1/area/getRoomList?platform=web&parent_area_id=4&cate_id=0&area_id=0&sort_type=online&page=1&page_size=15
2019-02-22 10:28:29,222 - C:\Users\Thinkpad\Desktop\BilibiliHelper\Src\Log.py[line:56] - DEBUG: STATUS: 200
2019-02-22 10:28:29,222 - C:\Users\Thinkpad\Desktop\BilibiliHelper\Src\Log.py[line:56] - DEBUG: <coroutine object ClientResponse.text at 0x000002C63BF24830>
C:\Users\Thinkpad\Desktop\BilibiliHelper\Src\AsyncioCurl.py:21: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'ClientResponse.text' was never awaited
  Log.debug(r.text())
Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished coro=<a() done, defined at .\Src\test.py:4> exception=TimeoutError()>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\Src\test.py", line 7, in a
    data = await AsyncioCurl().get(url,payload)
  File "C:\Users\Thinkpad\Desktop\BilibiliHelper\Src\AsyncioCurl.py", line 23, in get
    return await r.json()
  File "C:\Users\Thinkpad\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\client_reqrep.py", line 1017, in json
    await self.read()
  File "C:\Users\Thinkpad\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\client_reqrep.py", line 969, in read
    self._body = await self.content.read()
  File "C:\Users\Thinkpad\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\streams.py", line 359, in read
    block = await self.readany()
  File "C:\Users\Thinkpad\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\streams.py", line 381, in readany
    await self._wait('readany')
  File "C:\Users\Thinkpad\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\streams.py", line 297, in _wait
    await waiter
  File "C:\Users\Thinkpad\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\helpers.py", line 585, in __exit__
    raise asyncio.TimeoutError from None
concurrent.futures._base.TimeoutError
```

**test.py**

```
import asyncio
from AsyncioCurl import AsyncioCurl

async def a():
    payload = {}
    url = "https://api.live.bilibili.com/room/v1/area/getRoomList?platform=web&parent_area_id=4&cate_id=0&area_id=0&sort_type=online&page=1&page_size=15"
    data = await AsyncioCurl().get(url,payload)
    print(data)

task = [
    a()
]

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.wait(task))
```

**AsyncioCurl.py**

```
import asyncio
import aiohttp
from Log import Log
from Base import sign
from config import config


class AsyncioCurl:
    def __init__(self):
        self.session = aiohttp.ClientSession(timeout=aiohttp.ClientTimeout(total=4))

    async def get(self,url,param):
        Log.debug("GET: "+url)
        payload = {
            "cookie":config["Token"]["COOKIE"]
        }
        payload = dict(param,**payload)
        payload = sign(payload)
        async with self.session.get(url,params=payload) as r:
            Log.debug("STATUS: "+str(r.status))
            Log.debug(r.text())
            await self.session.close()
            return await r.json()

    async def post(self,url,param):
            Log.debug("POST: "+url)
            payload = {
                "cookie":config["Token"]["COOKIE"]
            }
            payload = dict(param,**payload)
            payload = sign(payload)
            async with self.session.post(url,data=payload) as r:
                await self.session.close()
                return await r.json()

    async def nspost(self,url,param):
        Log.debug("POST: "+url)
        headers = {
            "Accept":"application/json, text/plain, */*",
            "User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/62.0.3202.94 Safari/537.36",
            "Accept-Language":"zh-CN,zh;q=0.9",
            "accept-encoding":"gzip, deflate",
            "cookie":config["Token"]["COOKIE"]
        }
        async with self.session.post(url,data=param,headers=headers) as r:
            await self.session.close()
            return await r.json()

    async def nsdpost(self,url):
        Log.debug("POST: "+url)
        headers = {
            "Accept":"application/json, text/plain, */*",
            "User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/62.0.3202.94 Safari/537.36",
            "Accept-Language":"zh-CN,zh;q=0.9",
            "accept-encoding":"gzip, deflate",
            "cookie":config["Token"]["COOKIE"]
        }
        async with self.session.post(url,headers=headers) as r:
            return await r.json()
```

PS:Direct access this site is no error.

Comment: Your request took longer than the timeout.

Comment: I fount that I should not add the param.Thanks for your replying.

Comment: @user10733862 Could you please close this question as 'works for me'?

Answer (score 0):

The timeout set by the following line is too small. The request is taking longer time than 4 seconds.

```
self.session = aiohttp.ClientSession(timeout=aiohttp.ClientTimeout(total=4))
```

Please increase the timeout in seconds or remove the `timeout` parameter altogether.